# Pass date (Y-m-d) to a function variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
function getMovement(id, check_date) {
  console.log(check_date);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn btn-warning" type="button" onclick="getMovement(18, 2020-07-21)">Check me</button>
```

I have mysql date (Y-m-d) to pass into a function, but it is auto subtract and passed the subtract total into function, how can I pass the actual date inside the `getMovement()` and in the format of `Y-m-d`

Comment: You can pass as a string like this ```onclick="getMovement(18, '2020-07-21')">Check me</button>```

Comment: Thanks @HarmandeepSinghKalsi it's correct